# Ember cli cordova with torii simple auth

Tags: cordova, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Hi I am trying to use torii simple auth with ember cli cordova.

this is how torii works.

1. it send a request for authorization
2. app is redirected to entered url during creating app of fb with aurthorizatin code

I get popup fine when i click on facebook login button. I enter credentials but when fb return authorization code i get error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
I have changed app url to http : //localhost

How can i catch authorization code returned in cordova.

cordova cofig.xml

```
  <access origin="*" />
```

[image]

Comment: Did you set your fb app settings to accept localhost as auth url (I don't remember the exact term)?

Comment: Valid OAuth redirect URIs in advance setting of developer.facebook.com  http://localhost and http://localhost:4200

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm thinking about integrating Torii with my app in Cordova as well.

Comment: Hi the redirectURl document.location.href is giving error 'google-oauth2' :{
                  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxx',
                  redirectUri: **Problem**
                }, i did not figure out how to access window document object here